# Banno Messaging

Tags: messaging, banno-digital-toolkit

We are attempting to utilize Banno's Admin Messaging features, however, we are unsure of which API should be used. We'd like to see the envelope icon instead of the exclamation icon in the messaging center. Does anyone have any insight on which API would be best?

Answer (score 0):

The Admin API does not offer a way to change the icon.

See [**POST** a/mobile_api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/messages](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/messages/institution/#/Messages/post_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__messages) for more details on the relevant API endpoint.

Comment: Will the institutional messages allow for targeted messages? We would like to select specific individuals to send a messages to. I do not see that Post Institutional messages allows for this. What would you recommend using?